# How do I pivot my data using a T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to pivot my data so that the classification and Trade appear as headers. Below is an an example dataset.

| Description | Status | Issue_number | Custom_Label | Custom_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hydraulic | Open | 680 | Classification | Major |
| Hydraulic | Open | 680 | Trade | Pumps |
| Electrical | Closed | 681 | Classification | Minor |
| Electrical | Closed | 681 | Trade | Electrical |

This is my required output:

| Description | Status | Issue_number | Classification | Trade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hydraulic | Open | 680 | Major | Pumps |
| Electrical | Closed | 681 | Minor | Electrical |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `PIVOT` should do the trick

```
Select *
 From  YourTable 
 Pivot ( max( Custom_Value ) for Custom_Label in ( [Classification],[Trade] ) ) pvt
```

**EDIT -**

Just in case you have extra columns not listed above... you need to "feed" the pivot with only the required columns.

```
Select *
 From  ( Select Description
               ,Status
               ,Issue_number
               ,Custom_Label
               ,Custom_Value
         From  YourTable
        ) src
 Pivot ( max( Custom_Value ) for Custom_Label in ( [Classification],[Trade] ) ) pvt
```